# TCPDF Y Position Getting Reset

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using the TCPDF library to build a PDF to display results of a survey. I have the option to create a custom header to be added to the survey, that can be anything from an image to just text, which can be any size/length.

My problem is on an autobreak the Y position of the following page gets reset and runs with the header.

I am able to change the first page by capturing the current Y position and setting it after the "AddPage()" function. My issue is on the autopagebreaks that occur, I can't find anyway to check if this occurred and trigger something to happen.

I found the "checkpagebreak" but this doesn't work for when the pagebreak occurs during a multicell block of text. I checked the "custom header" example TCPDF has but it appears it uses a static sized header margin, I need to find a way to make that value dynamic.

I am using the following code

```
// **************************************************************************************
// Process Selection 
// **************************************************************************************
function RunReport()
{
// Make all global variables available here
    foreach($GLOBALS as $arraykey=>$arrayvalue) 
    {
        if ($arraykey != "GLOBALS")
        {
            global $$arraykey;
        }
    }
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    class PDF extends tcpdf
    {
        function Header()
        {
//This is pulled from a database but is filled in only to show the current data I am working with***
//          $this->S1LDESC = "<center>Test Application<br><img src=\"link/to/image\" width='208'; height='80'></img></center>";
            if(trim($this->S1LDESC) <> "")
            {
                $this->SetFont('Times','',11);
                $this->Cell(0, .5, "" , 0,1,'C', 0);
                $newX = $this->GetX();
                $newY = $this->GetY();
                $this->writeHTMLCell(0, .5, $newX, $newY, trim($this->S1LDESC) , 0,1,0, true, 'C', true);
            }
            $this->SetFont('Times','B',11);
            $this->Cell(0, .5, "" , 0,1,'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(0, .5, trim($this->S1DESC), 0, 1, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
            $this->HeadY = $this->GetY();           
            $this->SetY($this->GetY() + 5); 
        }
    }

    $pdf = new PDF("P", PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    $pdf->SelComp = $SelComp;
    $pdf->SelSchool = $SelSchool;

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false); 
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(true);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    //$pdf->SetY($pdf->HeadY);      

    $selstring = "SQL To Grab DATA";
    if (!($result = db2_exec($db2conn, $selstring, array('CURSOR' => DB2_SCROLLABLE)))) 
    {
        echo($selstring."<BR>");
        db2_close($db2conn);
        die("<b>Error RunReport  ". db2_stmt_error().":" . db2_stmt_errormsg()."</b><br>" . $selstring2); 
    }
    while($row = db2_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
        // make the file field names available in HTML
        foreach(array_keys($row) as $key)
        {
            $escapedField = $key;
            $$escapedField = $row[$key];                    
        }
        $pdf->SetFont('Times','B',11);
        if($HldGroup <> $S2GROUP)
        {
            $HldGroup = $S2GROUP;
            if(trim($S5GROUP) <> "*None")
            {
                //Write Group data
                $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, trim($S5GROUP), 0, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true);
                if(trim($S5GRPDESC) <> "")
                {
                    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, trim($S5GRPDESC), 0, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true);
                }
            }
        }
        if($S2QUESTTYP <> "HD")
        {
            $pdf->Cell(5, 0, "", 0,0,'C', 0);

            $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, trim($S2QUESTION), 0, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true);

            $pdf->SetFont('Times','',11);
            if($S2QUESTTYP <> "ND")
            {
                $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, trim($S2QUESTION), 0, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true);
            }
            else
            {
            }
            $pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, "", 0, 'L', 0, 1, '', '', true);
        }
    }

    //Print file with Student name and report name???
    $pdf->Output("$SurvName.pdf", 'I');
}
```

This results in the following:
Page 1:
[image: Page 1]

Page 2:
[image: Page 2]

Comment: Typically header customization would include a positioning of Y to leave space below the header before text starts. I typically use `$this->SetY($this->GetY() + 5);`. It looks like you are trying to do it during the PDF creation instead of letting the header function do it.

Comment: @Dave I tried this during one my tests and it still caused the same issue, it seems like the Y positon set in the header gets ignored and is reset when outside the Header funciton.

Comment: If that is happening it would have to be something in your code doing it.

Comment: Every time you draw something below the bottom margin you set in the `AutoPageBreak` function the `AddPage()` function is called which in turn calls the `Header()` function. You dont need to call `SetY()` just do `$this->Ln()` at the end of the `Header()`

Comment: I tried using $this->Ln() instead of the SetY and still go the same results. Is using writehtmlcell messing with something? If I take that line out everything works as expected but this isn't an option since I need it to work with writehtmlcell.